# opencv::findContours crashes even with small sized images (smaller than 200~pixels)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get contour points with OpenCV
I'm using openCV 2411 because of my main application works 32 bit and newer versions of Opencv are 64 bit only. My code is;

```
    Mat src = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);

Mat gThreshold = Mat(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8U);
threshold(src, gThreshold,128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

imshow("thres", gThreshold);
waitKey(0);
Mat dst = Mat(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC4);


std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(gThreshold, contours, hierarchy,       CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
  
int idx = 0;
for (; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
{
    Scalar color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
    drawContours(dst, contours, idx, color,1, 8, hierarchy);
}
imshow("con", dst);
waitKey(0);


return 1;
```

Normally this code works with small images (smaller than 200x200 pixel) but I can't get any result bigger than this size. It crashes every time.But crashes after showing threshold and contour images.

I tried with different type of images but nothing changed.
I searched stackoverflow and there are some same problems but I tried everything in answers nothing changed again.
I use release mode and libraries are ok. Is this about working on 32 bit? or am I missing something?

Comment: so the program crashes after showing threshold and contour images, but showing the contour images is the last thing your program does before exiting the main and cleaning up. this makes me think the problem may be elsewhere. can you reproduce the error with a smaller section of code? (i am assuming you arent sharing your entire program here) try to share the smallest complete program that can reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.In fact my all program is almost here because it's a DLL and calling from my app. But I realized that when using opencv's old versions it has only vs10 vs11 and vs12 libraries.When I use visual studio 2017 I choose opencv v12 libraries.I made 7 DLL's for my project before with this setup and they are all working except this one which uses findcontours.
I tried with visual studio 2012 express and now it's working.I guess this was a library mismatch problem.

Comment: good news. thanks for letting me know!